# How to completely remove Dart ubuntu?

Tags: flutter, ubuntu, dart

I have installed flutter and now removed it (removed directories) but if I do

```
sudo apt update
```

I get the following lines

```
Ign:5 https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable InRelease
Hit:6 https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable Release
```

how can I remove this dartlang.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's added its own repositories as a source for updates. These lines will either be in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` or in their own file in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Simply remove those lines (or the specific file if it's been added). Don't delete your whole `/etc/apt/sources.list`!

Comment: it was indeed in the sources.list.d directory, removed it and it works fine now!